# Temp table takes too long for select statement

Tags: sql-server, performance

[image]

The problem is line:
**LeadsWalkIn                   = CASE WHEN (WORK.WORK_ID NOT IN (SELECT WorkId FROM #WORKSHEETS) AND WORK.AGRA_ID = CU.AFFINITY_GROUP_ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,**
taking to long that I get the time out.
Is there any other way to get the same result faster?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry the image is not very visible. You can save the image and it would be ok.

Comment: Do not post code as images. Copy and paste it as TEXT please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the current #WORKSHEETS table definition (assuming that `WorkId` is guaranteed to be non-null), I'd avoid the subquery, and use an outer join operation instead. We need to guaranteed that there will be no more than one row that matches, so we can do a DISTINCT or a GROUP BY to get a unique list of WorkId...

```
 LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT WorkId FROM #WORKSHEETS ) w
   ON w.WorkId = WORK.WORK_ID
```

And then change the expression in the SELECT list, to check for a "no matching row" condition:

```
   CASE WHEN w.WorkId IS NULL AND ...
```

---

If the `#WORKSHEETS` table isn't being used for anything else, I'd consider inserting only unique values of WorkId, by adding a GROUP BY or DISTINCT to the query that populates the `#WORKSHEETS` table, and then use just a reference to `#WORKSHEETS` in place of the inline view query (`w`).

Adding an appropriate index on `#WORKSHEETS` may improve the performance of the join operation. That could even be a UNIQUE index if we only have distinct values of WorkId.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an index on #Worksheets after you have populated it, similar to:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndexName] ON [dbo].[#worksheets]
(
    [workid] ASC
)
```

Further optimizations are possible but it would make it easier if you posted the code as text not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The example Logic :

ex Data :

```
Work    xxx
-----------
A       A
B       B
x       C
x       D
E       x
F       x
```

if you wanna get result like this, with left join :

```
if WORK.AGRA_ID = CU.AFFINITY_GROUP_ID

Work    xxx    value
--------------------
A       A      0
B       B      0
E       x      1
F       x      1
```

try this one :

your select you chenge to :

```
LeadsWalkIn = CASE WHEN (xxx.WorkId is null AND WORK.AGRA_ID = CU.AFFINITY_GROUP_ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
```

and your join query add to last join :

```
Left Join #WORKSHEETS xxx On xxx.WorkId = WORK.WORK_ID
```

Comment: The proposed SQL changes make an assumption that `WorkId` is unique in `#WORKSHEETS` (it may be a valid assumption, but we don't have enough information to know that this is is actually guaranteed.) I also believe the join predicate would need to compare `WorkId` with `WORK.WORK_ID`, rather than `WORK.AGRA_ID`.